# Importing a CSV file into postgres - skip the first line

Tags: postgresql

How do I import a CSV file into postgres and make it skip the first line (it's just column titles).

I try:

```
\COPY products(sight, department) from 'coy.csv' with (FORMAT CSV);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding the HEADER line will account for the first line being column headers.

```
COPY products (sight,department) FROM 'coy.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html